Web API HTTP Status Code for locked records
I'm building an API where a user can request to select a specific record to process.
If successful, the user's UID is allocated against the record which locks the record from other users.
If another user then tried to select the same record, then they should be notified that the selected record has been locked by another user.
I'm not sure what the best way to relay the information via an API when this happens. I'm currently using BadRequest(result.Message)
But I'm not sure if that's the best way to relay these types of messages to a client.
There are other scenarios similar to this where a user may try to select a record but the record is not ready to be processed so they are also relayed a message to inform them of that.
How should an API relay these types of message to the client in terms of the HTTP status code?

Questions like this are opinion-based so don't really have a place here on Stack Overflow. The answer is: use whatever you like, just ensure the client can handle it.

Regarding locked resource, Id recommend using HTTP status code 423 Locked (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/423).
When the resource is not yet ready for end user, i think it would make sense to use 404 NOT Found (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)
Also, when returning info to client, aspecially error info, I'd recommend using defined error response contract, so the error responses would be consistent.
E.g.:
public class ErrorResponse
  {
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object Params { get; set; }

    public ErrorResponse()
    {
    }
 }


HTTP 423 is specific to WebDAV so I wouldn't recommend using it. 404 also has a lot of baggage associated with it so could be confusing.

You may be right, yet did not suggest any alternatives. Out of curiosity, what would you suggest and why?

400 would work, 409 perhaps. Even a 200 with a well-formed message structure. Doesn't really matter if the API has a reasonable amount of documentation to go with it.
